# How to tell if a SerializedProperty is part of an array in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I have a struct `Stat`

```
[Serializable]
public struct Stat {
    public string key;
    public string value;
}
```

I want it to display in the editor as a single line property with the label when it is a single non-array field, but when it is a part of an array I want to hide the label, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just check if the property path contains `"Array"`.

```cs
using (new EditorGUILayout.HorizontalScope())
{
    // Check if the property path contains "Array", also works for lists
    if (property.propertyPath.Contains("Array"))
    {
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField(property.displayName);
    }

    SerializedProperty keyProp = property.FindPropertyRelative("key");
    SerializedProperty valueProp = property.FindPropertyRelative("value");

    keyProp.stringValue = EditorGUILayout.TextField(keyProp.stringValue);
    valueProp.stringValue = EditorGUILayout.TextField(valueProp.stringValue);
}
```

Note that in the case of a property drawer, you can't use `GUILayout` functions, so you'll have to manage the draw rects by yourself. In that case, consider using `EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth` to draw the label with the expected width.

Here is an extension function to do the check directly from `SerializedProperty`:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public static class SerializedPropertyExtensions
{
    
    public static bool IsArrayElement(this SerializedProperty property)
    {
        return property.propertyPath.Contains("Array");
    }

}
```